# about the power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices, graph-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume that matrix $A$ contains only 0 or 1 elements. Could anyone give me some condition, under which the matrices $A^i$ (for $i=1,2,3,...,k$) still contains only 0 or 1 elements.

For example, I know that if $A$ is an identity matrix, then it satisfies the above condition. Could you provide me some general conditions about $A$ ?

Comment: If $B = A.A$ then $B_{i,j} = \sum_k A_{i,k}A_{k,j}$ so for the square to work out then the inner products of the rows of $A$ with the columns of $A$ have can only have a one in common at most one place.

Comment: In particular if any row (column) of $A$ has more than one $1$ in it, then no column (row) of $A$ can have a $1$ in the corresponding row (column). I hope that makes some sense. I can elaborate, if you'd like, with examples.

Comment: Well, it's fairly clear that any such matrix better have every eigenvalue be $1$, $-1$, $i$ or $-i$, since otherwise it would experience unbounded growth or shrinking in some dimension, either of which would be problematic.

Comment: @Meelo, could you elaborate on these eigenvalues with more intuitions?

Comment: @Meelo Shrinking does not hurt. Zero (or mostly zero) matrices fulfill the requirements. Actually the spectral *radius* bounded from above by one seems to be a more reasonable necessary condition.

Answer (score 4):

$A$ can be a permutation matrix, that is, a square matrix, each row or columns of contains exactly one $1$ and the rest $0$.

$\bf{Added:}$
One really should think about the associated oriented graph. The matrix $A^k$ has  the $(i,j)$ element equal to the number of walks of length $k$ from $i$ to $j$ ( I say walk because it could go back and forth if that is possible). Now we can get more example of such graphs. For instance, an oriented segment graph works.

Comment: Can you prove this condition is necessary?

Comment: @Meelo:It can have only a diagonal block a permutation matrix and the rest $0$.